# Exclude parts of default css import

Tags: css, import

I'm importing Twenty Thirteen's default stylesheet, but I want it to leave my buttons alone.

I could of course disable all mentions of "button" in the temaplate's `style.css`, but that would only work until the next update - I suppose.

Is there any way to exclude the styling of certain elements from being imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of Twenty Thirteen's default stylesheet and remove all unnecessary styles. After it import this copy instead of Twenty Thirteen's and after next update you won't loose your changes.

Comment: how did I not think of that? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to exclude the styling of certain elements from being
>   imported?

No. CSS is not that complicated.

I am assuming that you are creating a child theme. If so, what you can do is `enqueue` the parent, Twenty Thirteen stylesheet before you enqueue your child stylesheet. Then, any selectors listed in the child that match selectors in the parent will override the parent. The advantage of that over the solution by simply copying the parent stylesheet is that it should be more robust over time. Imagine that the markup of the parent changes. If you've copies the stylesheet meant for an older markup, you may have a stylesheet that is broken by beinig out of sync with the markup.

The disadvantage is that you will be loading more CSS than you need to be, maybe a lot more.

You can also just write your CSS rules to have more specific selector than the parent.